# How to get spacings around lists with Sphinx in the latexpdf output?

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx

I'd like to get top and bottom margins between lists and paragraphs in the latexpdf output of Sphinx.

The structure of my RST document is very simple :

```
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum


- Lorem ipsum
- Lorem ipsum
- Lorem ipsum


Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
```

Actually, I have this :

[image]

…but i'd like this :

[image]

I think there's no margin due to the fact that there's no blank line before `\begin{itemize}` in the latex output :

```
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
\begin{itemize}
\item {} 
Lorem ipsum

\item {} 
Lorem ipsum

\item {} 
Lorem ipsum

\end{itemize}
```

Because if i add a newline, it works:

```
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum

\begin{itemize}
\item {} 
Lorem ipsum

\item {} 
Lorem ipsum

\item {} 
Lorem ipsum

\end{itemize}
```

Is there a way to force Sphinx to add this blank line during the generation of the latex file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have this line in my Makefile before creating the PDF from the tex file and it works :

```
sed '/\\begin{itemize}/{x;p;x}' input > output
```